# Extracting rows matching conditions based on previous rows - r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that look like below:

```
  time = 1:22
  device =  c(rep(9,8), rep(3,6),rep(17,8))
  antenna = c(2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1)
  ID = c("A","A",NA,"B",NA,"B",NA,NA,"B",NA,"B",NA,"C",NA,"A","B",NA,NA,"B",NA,"B",NA)

  df <- data.frame(time, device,antenna,ID)

  df

#    time device antenna   ID
# 1     1      9       2    A
# 2     2      9       1    A
# 3     3      9       2 <NA>
# 4     4      9       2    B
# 5     5      9       1 <NA>
# 6     6      9       1    B
# 7     7      9       2 <NA>
# 8     8      9       1 <NA>
# 9     9      3       2    B
# 10   10      3       2 <NA>
# 11   11      3       2    B
# 12   12      3       2 <NA>
# 13   13      3       2    C
# 14   14      3       2 <NA>
# 15   15     17       1    A
# 16   16     17       2    B
# 17   17     17       1 <NA>
# 18   18     17       2 <NA>
# 19   19     17       1    B
# 20   20     17       1 <NA>
# 21   21     17       1    B
# 22   22     17       1 <NA>
```

There are a number of devices, each of which can have two antennas (1 or 2 - `antenna` column). In the ID column we have have an ID or NA.

What I need to extract are each row with an ID in them plus the next row in the dataset with an `NA` in the ID column that had the exact same device/antenna combination as the previous ID.

For instance, row 4 has device = 9, antenna = 2, id = B.  I need that row and the next row which has an NA but has device = 9, antenna = 2, ID = NA, which is row 7.

*Desired Output*

```
  #A: 
  df[c(1,3,2,5,15,17),]

#    time device antenna   ID
# 1     1      9       2    A
# 3     3      9       2 <NA>
# 2     2      9       1    A
# 5     5      9       1 <NA>
# 15   15     17       1    A
# 17   17     17       1 <NA>


  #B:
  df[c(4,7,6,8,9,10,11,12,16,18,19,20,21),]

#   time device antenna   ID
#4     4      9       2    B
#7     7      9       2 <NA>
#6     6      9       1    B
#8     8      9       1 <NA>
#9     9      3       2    B
#10   10      3       2 <NA>
#11   11      3       2    B
#12   12      3       2 <NA>
#16   16     17       2    B
#18   18     17       2 <NA>
#19   19     17       1    B
#20   20     17       1 <NA>
#21   21     17       1    B


  #C:
  df[c(13,14),]
 
#  time device antenna   ID
#13   13      3       2    C
#14   14      3       2 <NA>
```

I considered trying to do this by subsetting each device and antenna combination and then piecing together (although note that some device/antenna pairs may not show up in the data):

```
  subset(df, df$device==9 & df$antenna==2)
  subset(df, df$device==17 & df$antenna==1)
  subset(df, df$device==3 & df$antenna==1)
```

I'm wondering if my method will work or is there a better method?

Comment: Is there any chance that the first row, for a particular grouping of `device` | `antenna`, might ever have an `NA` for `ID`?

Comment: @Greg  Although highly unlikely, I cannot exclude this possibility unfortunately.  It could do.

Comment: Also, can we guarantee that each combo of `device` | `antenna` | `ID`, where `ID` is **not** `NA`, is in fact unique?  Or might there ever be rows like `9` | `2` | `"A"`; ...; `9` | `2` | `NA`; ...; `9` | `2` | `"A"`;  ...; `9` | `2` | `NA`?

Comment: @Greg each combo should be unique - yes

Comment: There does seem to be a dilemma in the dataset, then.  Are we trying to do the following: for each `k`th `ID` that is not `NA`, in its group of `device` | `antenna`, extract it along with the **`k`th _overall_** row that has `NA` for an `ID` and matches the `device` and `antenna`?  Or are we trying something else: for each `ID` that is not `NA`, extract it along with the **first _subsequent_** row that has `NA` for an `ID` and matches the `device` and `antenna`?  If the latter, then having the `NA` occur first could present a real problem, especially if there are no other `NA`s in its group.

Comment: @Greg  yes, it's the second of those options.  I think however what I can do is to remove all instances of `NA` that occur for each `antenna` `device` combination prior to there being an `ID` for that combination.  That should not be too hard in my actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Match function which finds the matching NA ID row given a non-NA row and then split df and apply it to each component.  Note that the time equals the row number in the question and we have assumed that.

```
Match <- function(row) {
  subset(df, device == row$device & 
                antenna == row$antenna &
                time > row$time &
                is.na(ID))[1, "time"]
}

f <- function(x) df[c(sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) c(x$time[i], Match(x[i, ])))), ]
lapply(split(df, df$ID), f)
```

giving:

```
$A
   time device antenna   ID
1     1      9       2    A
3     3      9       2 <NA>
2     2      9       1    A
5     5      9       1 <NA>
15   15     17       1    A
17   17     17       1 <NA>

$B
   time device antenna   ID
4     4      9       2    B
7     7      9       2 <NA>
6     6      9       1    B
8     8      9       1 <NA>
9     9      3       2    B
10   10      3       2 <NA>
11   11      3       2    B
12   12      3       2 <NA>
16   16     17       2    B
18   18     17       2 <NA>
19   19     17       1    B
20   20     17       1 <NA>
21   21     17       1    B
22   22     17       1 <NA>

$C
   time device antenna   ID
13   13      3       2    C
14   14      3       2 <NA>
```

Comment: How might we control for the [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134690/extracting-rows-matching-conditions-based-on-previous-rows-r#comment120423093_68134690) in which `NA` row occurs **before** (ie. above) its corresponding non-`NA` row?